# img tag doesn't work in ie8

Tags: internet-explorer-8, href

I have this code:

```
<div id="hidden_images" style="display:none">
                                            <?php
                                            $cant = 0;
                                            foreach($slidesDestacados as $s){
                                            ?>
                                                <div id='image_<?php echo $cant;?>' >
                                                    <a href="<?php echo $this->base."/Categorias/index/".$s['SlideDestacado']['link'];?>"><img src="<?php echo $this->base;?>/img/slides_destacados/<?php echo $s['SlideDestacado']['image_small'];?>"/> </a>
                                                    <div class="textte">
                                                        <span><?php echo $s['SlideDestacado']['title'];?></span>
                                                    </div>
                                                </div>  

                                            <?php
                                            $cant++;
                                            }
                                            ?>
                                        </div>
```

For some reason, it doesn't work in IE8, it just doesn't show the images (they are generated with their html ok).
I found that there are some compatibility issues with href and IE8, but couldn't solve it.

Any ideas?

**EDIT 1**

Generated HTML is this:

```
<div id="hidden_images" style="display:none">
                                                                                            <div id='image_0' >
                                                    <a href="/beneficios/Categorias/index/60"><img src="/beneficios/img/slides_destacados/tecno-smallx.jpg"/> </a>
                                                    <div class="textte">
                                                        <span>Beneficios en Tecnología</span>
```

Comment: If it's an issue with browsers rendering the HTML, what's the actual HTML?  The server-side code isn't really relevant to what the browser renders.

Comment: Please post a sample of the generated HTML. Also have you tried other browsers and if so do they work as expected?

Comment: <div id="hidden_images" style="display:none">
                       <div id='image_0' >
             <a href="/beneficios/Categorias/index/60"><img src="/beneficios/img/slides_destacados/tecno-smallx.jpg"/> </a>
             <div class="textte">
              <span>Beneficios en Tecnología</span>

Comment: Of course! it works on other browsers but I need working on IE8 too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<div id="hidden_images" style="display:none">
```

i would be shocked if this worked in any browser :)

remove the

> style="display:none"

Comment: Hey you are right! I didn't realize that! (I was taking for granted  that it was visible because I was changing the CSS with javascript)